# Why do we use redsocks+iptables instead of using iptables only?

Tags: proxy, routing, firewall, iptables

I can not understand why we use redsocks. Can't I do samething just using iptables to redirect all traffic to my socks proxy(that I create with ssh tunneling) ? What is the point of using redsocks ? We use iptables with redsocks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because “all traffic” does not speak the SOCKS protocol. A SOCKS proxy expects its clients to speak SOCKS. That’s where redsocks comes in: It *terminates* TCP connections and speaks SOCKS “on the other end”.

SOCKS is also a TCP-based protocol. When a SOCKS client connects, the following happens:

1. TCP handshake (SYN →, SYN-ACK ←, ACK →)
2. Client sends a SOCKS connection request ([as described on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#Protocol))
3. Server sends SOCKS response
4. (If successful thus far) Data exchange with actual target takes places (eg. sending an HTTP request)

If you just redirect whatever to the SOCKS proxy, this exchange will fail at step 2: The server will receive what it perceives to be garbage data (eg. the HTTP request that is supposed to come only in step 4) and terminate the connection.

Comment: Does a tcp package need any additional header to communicate with socks proxy port ? I think we don't need add any additional thing in the package to communicate with socks proxy. So Isn't it enough to just forward our packages to the socks proxy port with iptables ?

Comment: It doesn’t just need an additional header. SOCKS is an entire network protocol with its own semantics. You can read about it [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS).

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it totally!